# How to arrange two buttons side by side in Struts2

Tags: html, css, struts2

I am developing a Web page on struts2 If I am correct theme in Struts2 is set such that all the tags will eventually be inside a table so all tags will be aligned one below other.

In My web page i have login page with Submit and Reset button I want both side by side (next each other) rather than in separate line.I Tried googling i got some answer like                          `{ display : inline; }` in CSS and also `{ position : float}` and `theme="simple"` in form. Nothing worked

```
<table><tr><td><s:submit method="CheckUser" value="Login" align="center" /></td><td><s:reset value="Clear" align="center" /></td></tr>
```

In case if i set  i get the 2 buttons(submit+reset) as required
but though `label="User Id"` is given i get only text field without label

```
<tr><td><s:textfield name="userid" label="User Id" size="25" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><s:password name="password" label="Password" size="25" /></td></tr>
```

Please do suggest me where I am going wrong and how to get both label to text field and also   submit_Reset button side by side

Comment: It's using table elements for layout? You should change this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave default Struts2 theme, which is `xhtml` by the way, as it is and change only your `<s:submit>` and `<s:reset>` tags adding to them `theme` attribute with value `simple`.

```
<s:form>
  ... 
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <s:submit value="Login" theme="simple"/>
      <s:reset value="Clear" theme="simple"/>
    </td>
  </tr> 
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In struts.xml set the theme to simple

```
<struts>
   ...
   <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
   ...
<struts>
```

Now things will work as you expect.

The theme can also be scoped in other ways if you don't want the simple to to be default (page and per tag are common) see here: http://struts.apache.org/2.3.8/docs/selecting-themes.html