# Struts rendering my table wrong

Tags: java, html, struts2

Can someone Tell me, why my Table is rendered the wrong way?

```
<table class="ListingTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="border-left-style: hidden;">ProjectName</th>
                <th>CustomerID</th>
                <th>Leader</th>
                <th>DeadLine</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th style="border-right-style: hidden;"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <s:iterator value="projectMaps" status="Statusindex">
                <tr>
                    <td><s:property value="Name" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="CustomerID" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="Leader" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="DeadLine" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="Status" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="Details.action">
                            <s:hidden id="statusid" name="statusid" value="%{Index}" />
                            <s:submit type="submit" id="%{Index}" value="Details"
                                method="execute" style="height:20px;" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

It should look like this:
[image: The pic, of what it should look like]

But it looks like this:

[image: How it actually looks]

It must be within the `<form> </form>` because if I comment it out and replace it with just a Button, I get the result from the first picture.

It creates a new `<tr>` extra for each button, which I don't understand!

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/docs/themes-and-templates.html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to arrange two butons side by side in Struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009470/how-to-arrange-two-butons-side-by-side-in-struts2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `simple` theme to prevent the framework from generating the extra `<tr>`:

```xml
<s:submit type = "submit" 
            id = "%{Index}" 
         value = "Details"
        method = "execute" 
      cssStyle = "height:20px;" 
         theme = "simple" />
```

Also `style` should be `cssStyle` in Struts Tags.

And finally, avoid using DMI (Dynamic Method Invocation, the `method=""` part) because it is highly discouraged. It is not even needed if the method is `execute()`, the default one.

Read more about the different ways to set a theme [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27253495/1654265).

Answer (score 0):

add a style to your form display: inline-block;

```
<form action="Details.action" style="display: inline-block;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the form outside of the table. Something like this

```
<form>
   <table>
      ....
   </table>
</form>
```

and I think there is no use of `style="height:20px;"` in submit button.