# How to align two buttons side by side in struts 2

Tags: struts2

I am trying to align two buttons in struts2. I am beginner in struts so trying to figure out this. I am using `<s:submit`> tag. Its putting each button in a separate `<tr>` tag. That is why one button is coming below the second button. I want both the buttons side by side. Please provide information on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27941854/1654265

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to arrange two butons side by side in Struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009470/how-to-arrange-two-butons-side-by-side-in-struts2)